# JavaPOS can't claim device

Tags: java, javapos

I'm developing an application which implements JavaPOS. I have configured the setting correctly but I still not able to print the receipt. (I can make a print from CITIZEN JavaPOS TEST PRO Ver.1.3.4 but not from my program)

Here is some part of my code:

```
import jpos.*;
import jpos.util.JposPropertiesConst;
```

...

```
System.setProperty(JposPropertiesConst.JPOS_POPULATOR_FILE_PROP_NAME,"C:\\path_to_config\\jpos.xml");
```

...

```
POSPrinter printer = new POSPrinter();
try {
  printer.open("CITIZEN S310II USB Windows");
  printer.claim(100);
  printer.setDeviceEnabled(true);
  printer.setMapMode(POSPrinterConst.PTR_MM_METRIC);

  printer.transactionPrint(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, POSPrinterConst.PTR_TP_TRANSACTION);

  String LF     = ((char) 0x0a) + "";
  printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, "TEST" + LF + LF + LF);
  printer.cutPaper(100);
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  try {
    printer.setDeviceEnabled(false);
    printer.release();
    printer.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

....

The error occurred when I tried to call printer.claim(1000); stating

```
jpos.JposException: CSJjposCom access error.
    at com.citizen.jpos.b.e.d(Unknown Source)
    at com.citizen.jpos.b.e.claim(Unknown Source)
    at jpos.BaseJposControl.claim(Unknown Source)
    at simplepos.billUI.printBill(billUI.java)
    ....
```

My library are:

```
./CBMjpos.jar
./lib/comm.jar
./lib/jna.jar
./lib/xerces-2.6.0.jar
./lib/xerces2.jar
./lib/
```

Please help, I can't find any resource to fix this problem

Comment: Are you sure the test program is shutdown?

Comment: @JJF Yes. I even restarted my computer, still, showing the same error

Comment: i have notice that `CSJjposCom` is one of the provided `dll` (`CSJjposCom.dll` and `CSJjposBcw.dll`) so I have tried compiling with the flag `-Djava.library.path=`, still no use.

Comment: Do you have the source to the demo program?

Comment: @JJF Unfortunately, I don't have it.

Comment: Can you read any properties of the printer?  You might be right about the native library.   Claim is the first call that would cause the driver to try to make a call to the service object.  Also, you don't wnt the -Djava.library.path define on the compile phase.  You need to specifiy that define when you *RUN* your program.

Comment: My mistake. But the question is, how can you read properties of the printer if it's not claimed?

Comment: You should be able to read something like device name without having to claim the device.  Try anything.

Comment: @Suphakrit Phantharat Hi Suphakrit, I also came across the same problem with `jpos.JposException: CSJjposCom access` error while running Linux 64-Bit. Have you found a solution yet and would you mind sharing it with the community? Thank you very much for your efforts

Comment: @Chiggiddi sorry, i have not found any solution for me. Also, my printer doesn't support codepage that i wanted, thus having to print 3 lines for one actual line. I moved on to printing pdf instread :(

Answer (score 0):

It is occurred because of special permission needed.

Add this in manifest file and try.
Help for me.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```